# Initial chromecast setup

Tags: chromecast

excited to finally have some time to try developing on my chromecast but alas... can't even seem to get started.

I filled in the whitelist request, got the email confirming friday ( just in time for the weekend!), then I started looking at the samples and based on some I found wanted to get the hello world working.

1. Configured the chrome cast to send the serial to google through the Mac chromecast app
2. whitelisted the urls in the developer menu
3. verified that the receiver code is actually on the same URL that the registration stated ( copy pasted from the confirmation email and it works).

What happens is I open my sender HTML from my server or my localhost and I can't seem to get the chromecast to show up ( yes I am on the same network).

I added logs to the code to verify if the event message was being received and it is NOT being received so I'm guessing it is something with the extension not being able to validate the app ID.

is there a log for the extension I can look into?

here is the sender code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-cast-api-enabled="true">
<head>
<title>Hello sender!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="receiver-div">
                <h3>Choose A Receiver</h3>
                <ul class="receiver-list">
                    <li>Looking for receivers...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <button class="kill" disabled>Kill the Connection</button>
</body>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
        var cast_api,
            cv_activity,
            receiverList,
            $killSwitch = $('.kill');
            console.log("initializing script");

        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            console.log('Message received of type'+event.data.event);
            if (event.source === window && event.data &&
                    event.data.source === 'CastApi' &&
                    event.data.event === 'Hello') {
                initializeApi();
            }
        });

        initializeApi = function() {
                console.log('Initialize API called');
            if (!cast_api) {
                console.log("no cast api yet")
                cast_api = new cast.Api();
                cast_api.addReceiverListener('myidstring here', onReceiverList);
            }
        };

        onReceiverList = function(list) {
            console.log('on receiverlist called');
            if (list.length > 0) {
                receiverList = list;
                $('.receiver-list').empty();
                receiverList.forEach(function(receiver) {
                    $listItem = $('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + receiver.id + '">' + receiver.name + '</a></li>');
                    $listItem.on('click', receiverClicked);
                    $('.receiver-list').append($listItem);
                });
            }
        };

        receiverClicked = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $target = $(e.target),
                receiver = _.find(receiverList, function(receiver) {
                    return receiver.id === $target.data('id');
                });

            doLaunch(receiver);
        };

        doLaunch = function(receiver) {
            if (!cv_activity) {
                var request = new cast.LaunchRequest('still my id string here', receiver);

                $killSwitch.prop('disabled', false);

                cast_api.launch(request, onLaunch);
            }
        };

        onLaunch = function(activity) {
            if (activity.status === 'running') {
                cv_activity = activity;

                cast_api.sendMessage(cv_activity.activityId, 'charz', {type: 'HelloWorld'});
            }
        };

        $killSwitch.on('click', function() {
            cast_api.stopActivity(cv_activity.activityId, function(){
                cv_activity = null;

                $killSwitch.prop('disabled', true);
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

the only thing that gets logged is the "initializing script" line.

thank you in advance,

CR.

EDIT: 
I will mark Ali's answer as the answer as he put me on the path to fix it:
the fact that debug meant whitelist had been done, had me look into the configuration on my side:

1. file:// URLs do NOT work
2. when I set up on own web server locally, with localhost/sender.html it works immediately.
3. the whitelist MUST BE EXACT and not include the protocol ( apparently). I had whitelisted my url as : `http://myserver/mypath/sender.html`, and it did not work, finally adding the `myserver/mypath/sender.html` made it work flawlessly.

Maybe the doc could be updated to reflect this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing `http://<chromecast-ip>:9222` to see if your device is whitelisted correctly. You should see a page with a simple link in there that would open chrome debugger for your receiver.

Comment: Yes This works, so in essence the device is whitelisted. But it does not fire the "message" event.

Comment: thank you for all your help, Ali helped a lot through email at all hours!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, setup the URLs your way but it didn't help. Found my device IP and it is in development mode. I don't see anywhere to whitelist a URL in the developers menu... is that what I'm missing?

Comment: HTTPS is only required when you publish your app. As for your issue, can you be more specific: (1)can you access http://<chromecast-ip>:9222 ?

Comment: Well, I got it working originally by restoring factory settings and rebooting. It was casting fine a couple days ago. Now I haven't changed any of the cast-related code, and I'm getting "receiver list empty" again. I can access chromecastIP:9222. Tried the same process w factory reset, but no luck this time. On the same network, same computer. I'm getting re-stumped! The tab sees it but when I try to connect it just shows the "Casting to..." message indefinitely.

Comment: I am also new to chromecast development - how to I know what IP my chromecast is using? I need that IP to check against the port 9222...

Comment: Use the Android's Chromecast set up app; that gives you the ip address of the device.