# ChromeCast - Empty receiver list

Tags: chromecast

I'm developping a sender/receiver application but, in my sender app, in always get an empty receiver list.

I did:

- Whitelist my ChromeCast and my receiver page and I received my App ID from Google
- Tick the box: "send this Chromecast serial number to google when checking for updates" and wait more than 1 day
- Install ChromeCast Chrome extension, allow my domain and tick the "developper mode" box on chrome://extensions
- I used this Github to avoid JS mistakes: https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world (I also try with other exemples, without success)
- I put my App ID and set a NameSpace on my app
- My ChromeCast can access to my receiver page.

If I put "Youtube" as appId, my sender app can find my ChromeCast.

I can cast a Chrome Tab and Youtube Android App can cast too.

**I can't access to my_chromecast_ip:9222**, I found this topics: [Initial chromecast setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203080/initial-chromecast-setup) and [Initial chromecast setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203080/initial-chromecast-setup) it can be my solution but I wanted to ask here before use chromecast-updates@google.com to check if I miss something.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Since this issue appears to be more of an account access type of issue, please contact us at: chromecast-updates@google.com so that I can assist you further. Regards,
Adam

Comment: I'm having the same issue, despite I can see the debug link when accessing my_chromecast_ip:9222, but my receiver is still not showing ing in receiver list. Is it something related to the whitelisting or an error the code of chromecast-hello-world ?

Comment: Same issue here, but I can access the dev tools via my IP.

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but sometimes you need to reboot your chromecast and/or wait 15 minutes.

Comment: @CyrilleGuimezanes you should accept the answer which best answers your question.  It will help make it easier for others who come across this question to know which answer to look at first.

Comment: Actually, as I have no Chromecast anymore, I'm not able to say which answer is the right one and no answer scrore is enough revelant...

Answer (score 2):

Make *absolutely* sure that the device serial ID you entered in Google Cast SDK Developer Console is correct. I accidentally made a typo when entering my device's serial number ('I' vs '1'). The best way to make sure is to press on this little icon when registering your device. It will be loud and clear, and they use a serif font so you can't mix things like 'l' and 'I' and '1'.

[image]

If you found your typo, don't forget to reboot your chromecast device as soon as you see "*Ready For Testing*" in Google Cast SDK Developer Console.

Comment: Thanks for leaving this helpful answer behind.  Just a friendly reminder: on SO you should accept whichever answer answers your question (in this case, your own answer).

Comment: @machineghost thanks! but we're not allowed to up-vote our own answer on stack overflow.

Comment: Correct, but up-voting (clicking on the "up arrow") and accepting (clicking on the pale green checkmark) are two different things.  Up-voting your own answer = impossible.  Accepting the correct answer (whether it's your's or someone else's) = essential part of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @machineghost Only the author of the question can chose which answer is correct. Only CyrilleGuimezanes can see and click on the pale green checkmark, not me.

Comment: My apologies!  For some reason I thought you were the question author (too many SO tabs open at once ...)  I'll direct my comment to @CyrilleGuimezanes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the issue a lot when building my sender app and after doing my research, this is how to you solve the problem.

1. Add your sender app on localhost & Make sure your chromecast is on.
2. Turn on developer mode on Chrome (F12) and refresh your sender app. Make sure there is no error when initialize the Chrome Cast. If there is no error, you should see the ChromeCast-extension found : ..... in your Developer Console. If there is any error during initialization ChromeCast process in your sender app, the ChromeCast receiver will not appear in Extension popup.
3. If initializing the ChromeCast has no error but you still can not see your Receiver, simply close your ChromeCast browser (and try to clear your Chrome's cache if possible) and reload your sender app.

Hope this help.

Comment: tried all of the above. still getting `receiver list empty` when I use my own unpublished app ID. Works fine when I use the sample's default receiver app ID

Comment: found my issue: made a typo when entering my device's serial number ( I vs 1). it works now.

Comment: @michasson Glad that it helped. Please mark my answer as the right answer if it did help

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world
this sample is an old format.

```
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}
```

doesnt work with this code.
cant get "receiver list"

please try following

```
window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function(loaded, errorInfo) {
  if (loaded) {
    initializeCastApi();
  } else {
    console.log(errorInfo);
  }
}
```

reference:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender?hl=ja#Initialization

Comment: didn't help for me. Still getting `receiver list empty` when I use my own unpublished app ID. Works fine when I use the sample's default receiver app ID.

Comment: found my issue: made a typo when entering my device's serial number ( I vs 1). it works now.